# How to unnest array with keys to join on afterwards?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I have two tables, namely `table1` and `table2`. `table1` is big, whereas `table2` is small. Also, I have a UDF function whose interface is defined as below:

```
--table1--
id
1
2
3

--table2--
category
a
b
c
d
e
f
g

UDF: foo(id: Int): List[String]
```

I intend to call UDF firstly to get the corresponding categories: `foo(table1.id)`, which will return a WrappedArray, then I want to join every `category` in `table2` to do some more manipulation. The expected result should look like this:

```
--view--

id,category
1,a
1,c
1,d
2,b
2,c
3,e
3,f
3,g
```

I try to find a unnest method in Hive, but with no luck, could anyone help me out? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe that you want to use `explode` [function](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$) or Dataset's `flatMap` [operator](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset).

`explode` function creates a new row for each element in the given array or map column.

`flatMap` operator returns a new Dataset by first applying a function to all elements of this Dataset, and then flattening the results.

After you execute your UDF `foo(id: Int): List[String]` you'll end up with a `Dataset` with the column of type `array`.

```
val fooUDF = udf { id: Int => ('a' to ('a'.toInt + id).toChar).map(_.toString) }

// table1 with fooUDF applied
val table1 = spark.range(3).withColumn("foo", fooUDF('id))

scala> table1.show
+---+---------+
| id|      foo|
+---+---------+
|  0|      [a]|
|  1|   [a, b]|
|  2|[a, b, c]|
+---+---------+

scala> table1.printSchema
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = false)
 |-- foo: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)

scala> table1.withColumn("fooExploded", explode($"foo")).show
+---+---------+-----------+
| id|      foo|fooExploded|
+---+---------+-----------+
|  0|      [a]|          a|
|  1|   [a, b]|          a|
|  1|   [a, b]|          b|
|  2|[a, b, c]|          a|
|  2|[a, b, c]|          b|
|  2|[a, b, c]|          c|
+---+---------+-----------+
```

With that, `join` should be quite easy.